# How to concatenate different row values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance, concatenation

I'm tryng to concatenate the differents 'Z' values from this query..
This is working but its too slow, my table has 1M records.

Any idea how to make this performant?

```
SELECT distinct A,B,C,D,E,F,G
    ,(ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + RTRIM(Z)
    from DBO.TABLA a
    WHERE Z is not null and a.A = A
    and B =  a.B and C =  a.C
    and D =  a.D and E =  a.E
    and F =  a.F and G =  a.G
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    , ''))                      
     as blabla
```

Comment: You could make a CLR function to do groupwise concatenation.

Comment: You need to post the execution plan - Ctrl + M before executing the query in SSMS.

Comment: Done already the CLR function to do groupwise concatenation withouth succes, it is slower

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up with query with indexes.  I would recommend an index on `tabla(b, c, d, e, f, g, z)`.